# SQL calculating query

Tags: sql

In SQL how to show salary + 10% for SalesJob title and salary + 15% for other Job title?

Answer (score 1):

Who am I to argue with Gordon's advice?  You can use a `CASE` expression to determine which salary to report based on title.

```
SELECT title,
       CASE WHEN title = 'Sales' THEN 1.1 * salary ELSE 1.15 * salary END AS salary
FROM yourTable
```

Based on your suggested query you might try this:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN job = 'sales' THEN salary * 1.10
            ELSE salary * 1.20 END AS salary
FROM employees t
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for de reply, but keep receiving a error:SELECT *
from employees
CASE WHEN job = 'sales' THEN salary * 1.10 else salary * 1.20
    END as salary; My SQL is giving me a error in line #CASE WHEN job = 'sales' THEN salary * 1.10 else salary * 1.20#

Comment: @PauloSilva I don't know if you pasted that query verbatim, but if you did, then you have things out of order.